# Потоки или мультипроцессы?

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

Создаю скрипт суть которого получать некоторые данные с сайтов, работать все должно параллельно, решил использовать многопоточность, но, почитав в интернете, узнал что существует еще и многопроцессорность. У каждого из способ есть свои плюсы и минусы (процессов нельзя создать больше ядер, а если создать много потоков, то, как я понял, они будут мешать друг другу и смысла в потоках тогда нет) для каждой задачи, подскажите что мне лучше использовать? Суть задачи: До 30 потоков(процессов), связи между потоками не нужны

Comment: «процессов нельзя создать больше ядер» — неправда

Comment: @andreymal На заборе, кхм, сайте так было написано)

Comment: Скорее всего там было написано что-то про то, что процессов *нет смысла* создавать больше чем число ядер. Впрочем, потоков тоже

Comment: @andreymal Ну скорее всего так, так как мне лучше поступить, мне до 30 штук надо

Comment: Ну и вообще ответ на вопрос очень сильно зависит от конкретной задачи. Бывают такие задачи, для которых и одного процесса/потока более чем достаточно для выполнения хоть тысяч задач. С текйщей формулировкой вопроса однозначно и точно ответить не получится

Comment: @andreymal В двух словах: есть сайт и 30 ссылок с него, я каждые 10 сек с каждой ссылки беру информацию, в один поток делать не вариант потому что сайт частенько лежит, и получится очень долго

Comment: Это прекрасно делается в один поток с помощью asyncio

Comment: Но если вам неохота разбираться в asyncio и если выбирать между потоками и процессами, то разницы (по крайней мере заметной на глаз) всё равно не будет, потому что «бутылочным горлышком» в задачах подобного типа обычно является не процессор

Answer (score 0):

30 потоков на среднестатистической машине могут (и, скорее всего будут) работать хуже 4ех или 8ми. Т.к. на переключения между ними не малые затраты.
Если принципиально количество потоков, а не скорость работы, либо же у Вас дохрена мощный, многоядерный процессор, и цель - просто запараллелить код, то смело используйте потоки.
Сам делал подобное, на 2.7 пайтоне. Имелся 24ех ядерный компутер, и требовалось параллельно парсить кучу данных из сети. Узким местом стала сетевуха. Самые лучшие результаты были на 4ех потоках. Тот же код, запущенный на мобилке (2012год) работал в два раза продуктивнее, т.к. сетевуха успевала обслужить 8 потоков.

Comment: А если нет столько мощностей, то процессы?

Comment: Нее, процессы тяжелее потоков.

Comment: Используйте потоки.

Comment: Спасибо, понял, теперь рассуждаю потоки или asyncio ))

Comment: я же написал. Мобилке 2012ого года тянула 8 потоков, в каждом из которых работа с сетью.

Comment: @АлексейТихонов Просто подумайте что у вас занимает основное время - если ожидание пока ответит удаленный сайт, то вам потоки ничем не помогут, только бесполезно нагрузят систему. В данном случае только асинхронность в пределах одного потока. Если же вы быстро получаете страницу и потом долго ее обрабатываете, с большими затратами процессорного времени, тогда потоки/процессы, что удобнее